# Nsis. multiple conditions in doWhile loop

Tags: scripting, windows-installer, nsis

I'm trying to find out if several processes exist.

C++:

```
while (cond1 || cond2) {
   ...
}
```

How can I implement it using NSIS? I need something like this:

```
${DoWhile} cond1 or cond2
   ... 
${Loop}
```

or even this

```
${DoWhile} true
${If} cond1
${OrIf} cond2
   ... 
${EndIf}
${Loop}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Do+Loop without a condition:

```
!include LogicLib.nsh

${Do}
    ${If} $1 <> 0
    ${OrIf} $2 <> 0
        # ...
    ${Else}
        ${Break}
    ${EndIf}
${Loop}
```

Using a label works as well:

```
loop:
${If} $1 <> 0
${OrIf} $2 <> 0
    # ...
    Goto loop
${EndIf}
```